# update/upsert if duplicatekeyexception on insert mongodb java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

My application mostly does insert operation to mongodb by using mongodb java driver 3.2.2.

I would receive an document which I would have to insert, about 90% of the time, and  I have two unique key indexes defined on my collection.Occasionally when I receive a duplicate element , I am relying on the the driver throwing me an exception DuplicateKeyException, on which I know I want to update the document.

My document would look something like below:

```
{_id:{Object....},
name:"something", //unique key
rollNo:1232,   //unique key combined with name
otherfields
}
```

My Java code looks like below.

```
try{
dbCollections.insert(dbObject);
}catch(DuplicateKeyException e){
// since it is duplicate , lets just update it, 
}
```

I have the following questions

1. Am I on right track ?  I am trying to reduce any network round trip,by going with this approach.
2. The data am receiving in case of duplicate element could be very different from the original one , and am not sure which of the fields could have changed. so am not sure what operation I should choose update/upsert little confused here.

Answer (score 1):

you can turn your insert into update with UPSERT flag [ref](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html?_ga=1.130211016.639124630.1452026534#updateOne-org.bson.conversions.Bson-org.bson.conversions.Bson-) this will reduce exception handling, and insert new document where ID not exists, also save network traffic.

```
UpdateResult updateOne(Bson filter,
                       Bson update,
                       UpdateOptions updateOptions)
Update a single document in the collection according to the specified arguments.
Parameters:
filter - a document describing the query filter, which may not be null.
update - a document describing the update, which may not be null. The update to apply must include only update operators.
updateOptions - the options to apply to the update operation
Returns:
the result of the update one operation
Throws:
MongoWriteException - if the write failed due some other failure specific to the update command
MongoWriteConcernException - if the write failed due being unable to fulfil the write concern
MongoException - if the write failed due some other failure
```